# Failed to resolve IP Address nmap on Kali Linux

Tags: bash, nmap

I wrote a bash script for a simple scanner. It asks the user for the first and last IP addresses as well as the port number then stores them into variables. It then uses nmap to scan the range of ip addresses for open MySQL ports.

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is the first IP address?"

read firstIP

echo "What is the last IP address?"

read lastIP

echo "What port number do you want to scan?"

read port

nmap -sT $firstIP-$lastIP -p $port >/dev/null -oG MySQLscan

cat MySQLscan | grep open MySQLscan2

cat MySQlscan2
```

For the first prompt, I entered 192.168.181.0. For the second prompt, I entered 192.168.181.255. For the port number, I entered 3306. However, the result I got was:

> Failed to resolve "192.168.181.0-192.168.181.255"
>
> WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.

Why is it failing to resolve the IP addresses?

Comment: Since `grep` outputs to stdout and takes input filenames as arguments, you could simplify the last 2 lines as `grep open MySQLscan`; as it is, grep will try to *read* `MySQLscan2` as input.

Answer (score 2):

In `nmap`, you should specify that range of IP addrs in one the of following forms:

1. `192.168.181.0/24`
2. `192.168.181.0-255`

Thus, the correct way is either `<start_ip_addr>/<subnet_mask>` (will scan all the IPs under that subnet, starting from the provided one) or `<start_ip_addr>-<last_term_in_subnet_range>` (will scan up to the last given term, starting from the provided IP).

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue. No need to change my code, I just entered 255 for the second prompt and it worked.

Comment: Glad to know that! You can mark the answer in order to close the question.

Comment: To be clear, Nmap accepts ranges within a single octet of the IPv4 address. So for instance you could scan the first address of each possible RFC1918 class-C private network with this specification: `192.168.0-256.1`.